# Text Editor that can link images via drag-n-drop

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editors

I'm looking for a text editor where you can drag-n-drop images into your document, and the images are then linked from their original location. With "linked", I mean that they are displayed inside the document, but are not stored in the document file.

As far as I know, Word can do this linking - but it doesn't work with Drag-n-Drop. Drag-n-Drop always causes the file to be embedded in Word.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Word will do this, with a tiny modification. When you drag-and-drop, use the right mouse button. When you release the mouse button, you will get a prompt asking what you want to do. One of the options will be to **Create Hyperlink Here**.

Comment: When I do this in Word 2003, it inserts a hyperlink that shows the image path as a text. What I want to do instead is display the image inside the document. Updated my question, it previously wasn't too clear about that.